# PHP failing to check conditions

Tags: php, image, minecraft

im working on a script that shows Minecraft faces based on URL, but i got a problem, everytime an invalid username is inputed, it saves it into the skins folder, a thing it should only do when when a username IS valid.
full script:

```
Sorry, the problem has been already solved, i'm not going to give my script away.
```

It's quite long i know, but it's the full script.
So i remind, the problem is that the script saves invalid usernames too, a thing it should only do if a username is vaild.

Comment: Please post only that part of code with which you've got problems.

Comment: if you would actually read you would find a section of the code that clearly says //this is where my problem, i am trying to only display the image on screen if not found, but for some reason it saves it to the skins folder

Comment: If you would really care about getting answer, you'll post only necessary code or at least tell that there is any mark in code.

Comment: It is way easeir to work with full script because then you know exactly what the script does

Answer (score 0):

Try to add exit of wrap all other code in else{ } statement

```
 if(!$src){
    $src = imagecreatefrompng("http://s3.amazonaws.com/MinecraftSkins/char.png");
    //here's where my problem, i am trying to only display the image on screen if not found, but for some reason it saves it into the skins folder
    imagepng($final);
    **exit();**
    }
```

Comment: Maybe problem in this: $defailt not $default

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-existing api made by minotar; To get my skin "Phyore" You use https://minotar.net/avatar/Phyore when Minotar doesn't recognise the username (Doesn't exist) it'll give you the steve head.

```
$user = 'Phyore';
//Size defaults to 180 x 180
$size = '100';
echo '<img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/'.$user.'/'.$size.'"';
```

See more at https://minotar.net/ They even do full skins.

Comment: The whole point is to make my own script, not to embed Minotar into my own script.